# Django Error: user_register_model matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How to fix This Error I'm Trying To Fix This Error But I Get Again And Again
i want to detect user who fill the form for example test fill the form but when i write the code down below i get this error

Any Help Will Be Appreciated!

**ERROR**

```
user_register_model matching query does not exist.
```

**ERROR SCREENSHOT**

[image]

Here is my **Views.py**

```
def buy_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usr_buy = user_buy_form(request.POST)
        if usr_buy.is_valid():
            usr_buys = usr_buy.save(commit=False)
            user_register_obj = user_register_model.objects.get(user=request.user)
            usr_buys.users = user_register_obj
            usr_buys.save()
        else:
            return print(usr_buy.errors)

    else:
        usr_buy = user_buy_form()

    context = {'usr_buy':usr_buy}

    return render(request,'user_buy.html',context)
```

Here is my **Models.py**

```
class user_register_model(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class user_buy(models.Model):
    users = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    Trade_limits = models.IntegerField()
    Location = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.users.user.username
```

Here is my **Forms.py**

```
class user_buy_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = user_buy
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('users',)
```

Here is my **user_buy.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body_block %}
<form class="form-control" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{usr_buy.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: where is user_register_model

Comment: @arjun question updated

Comment: Is there any specific reason for writing this `user_register_model` ?I didn't see any points here

Comment: no i only want to query user and detect which user fill the form

Comment: @arjun i fix this error while typing like this `user_register_obj = User.objects.get(username=request.user)` you always help me thanks for asking but i solve my problem Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't see any points here to create the `user_register_model`.If you are trying to add the currently logged in user you can do this:

`request.user` will give you the currently logged in user so for this the user must be logged in.

```
    @login_required
    def buy_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        usr_buy = user_buy_form(request.POST)
        if usr_buy.is_valid():
            usr_buys = usr_buy.save(commit=False)
            usr_buys.users = request.user
            usr_buys.save()
            return redirect('some_path') # redirect to some path after saving the form
```

Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.

Comment: you always help me Thank you Very Much And Also Thank You For Your Attention

Answer (score 1):

I think the request.user is not present in the user_register_model model thats why it is giving matching query doesnot  exist error, first create it in the user_register_model and then query it.